# Python Use Pickle To Export and Import Multiple Cookies From One File

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, cookies, pickle

I'm trying to export cookies from multiple domains to one pickle file. But it is not working to load them back in..

My code:

```
p1 = pickle.load(open("/webdrivers/cookies_D.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in p1:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

p2 = pickle.load(open("/webdrivers/cookies_D.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in p2:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

p3 = pickle.load(open("/webdrivers/cookies_D.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in p3:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

p4 = pickle.load(open("/webdrivers/cookies_D.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in p4:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
sleep(4)
p1 = pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("/webdrivers/cookies_D.pkl","wb"))
sleep(4)

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
sleep(4)
p2 = pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("/webdrivers/cookies_D.pkl","ab"))
sleep(4)

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
sleep(4)
p3 = pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("/webdrivers/cookies_D.pkl","ab"))
sleep(4)

driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")
sleep(4)
p4 = pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("/webdrivers/cookies_D.pkl","ab"))
sleep(4)
```

I, of course, disable the `p1` to `p4` `load ()` code when I create the `pkl` cookie files.

If I for instance only create the first `google.com` `pkl` cookie file with the wb option it works to load it again. But if I use wb for all domains it just removes the already exported cookies and that is not what I want. I want to save all cookies of all domains and later load them all back up again.

Hope someone can help, and thanks up front.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are by design per-domain, otherwise it was a security breach. For this reason, whenever you navigate to another site, you can see only this site's cookies.

You can also see the cookies in the developer tool. You'll see that it behaves the same.